# How to Deal with Redundant/Repeated Imports in Python Modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I am writing a python module with multiple files, and files in sub-directories.

For example, lets say the base directory is `./package`, sub-directory `./package/sub` and files `./package/sub/file1.py` and `./package/file2.py`.

In `./package/sub/file1.py`, I imported the following third-party modules:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
```

In `./package/file2.py`, I imported the same modules from earlier, as well as the module present in the sub folder like so:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import sub.file1 as sub
```

Now, it turns out that `sub` has its own version of `pickle` under `sub.pickle`, and then file1 and file2 has their own version of pickle. Is there any way to remove this kind of redundancy?

If it is not a problem, does anyone know if both pickle imports will refer to the same region of memory?

Is there a better way I could have designed my code around imports?

Comment: "Now, it turns out that sub has its own version of pickle under sub.pickle, and then file1 has file2 has its own version of pickle" - no they don't. The Python import system doesn't make new versions of modules on every import. What made you think separate versions were created?

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to do anything. Python import system uses a cache (in the `sys.modules` dictionary) to prevent a module from being imported twice. Calling `import` with the same name anywhere in your code will yield the same module object from the first time, thus making module objects kind of "singletons".

Comment: Does it happen in all versions of python?

Comment: @Ehsan yes, it is a basic feature of the language. `import` is not `include`!

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. This is great to hear.